# I'm getting Validation error in mongoose when trying to post request

Tags: node.js, mongodb, api, express, mongoose

I'm getting the following error after sending the post request
I have validated the submitted fields.
It's working fine with GET method but throws an error when I try POST

Console error
[image]

Here is my schema

```
const alienShcema = new mongoose.Schema({

    name:
    {
        type: String,
        required: true
    }
 
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('Alien',alienShcema)
```

Here is the route file

```
router.post('/', async(req,res) =>{
    const alien = new Alien({
        name: req.body.name
      /*  tech: req.body.tech,
        sub: req.body.sub */
    })

    try{ 
        const  a1 = await alien.save()
        res.json(a1)

    } catch (err){
        console.log(err);
        res.send('Error')
    }
})

module.exports = router
```

Comment: What's the value of `req.body` in the `router.post('/'`? The error seems quite obvious to me.  The error essentialy says `req.body.name` is undefined. Can you show the code you use to send the POST request.

Comment: console.log req.body.name and see the output